# Run MATLAB script from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab

I am accessing a remote system and the way to launch MATLAB is to execute the following after doing `ssh` on ubuntu terminal.

```
/media/data/software/matlab2018a/bin/matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash
```

which opens a simple vi kind interface of MATLAB without opening the full GUI.

`/media/data/software/matlab2018a/bin/matlab` is the location of my MATLAB exe file and `-nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash` basically tells not to open full MATLAB GUI as working on remote desktop.

Now when I am inside the MATLAB editor I run the following to execute the MATLAB script `script_name`

```
cd location_of_script
script_name
```

`script_name` basically reads some images generated by Python, does some processing and saves the results in some `.txt` file.

*I want to unify this two step procedure*. That is as soon as my Python function is done with its job it should call the MATLAB script and terminate only when `.txt` file is saved.

The script does not require any input parameter.

Thankyou

Comment: Try this. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to start MATLAB from Python.

---

When you launch MATLAB, you should use the following startup flags:

- `sd` To set the MATLAB working directory.
- `-r` To execute the statement which MATLAB will run.

More info on the startup options [here.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("/media/data/software/matlab2018a/bin/matlab -sd \"location_of_script\" -r \"run('script_name');exit\" -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash")
```

Comment: Can you please provide me with more explanation?
Do you want me to do the following in the end of my Python code, `import os
os.system(str)` where `str` is the code in your answer?

Comment: Thankyou for the updated solution. I checked the MATLAB help page that you have referred. Why do you use a \ after -sd as in `-sd \"location_of..."`. Similalry there is a \ after -r as in `-r \ "run...`. From the MATLAB help page they do not use these slash. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The backslash is used to escape the `"` character. It's needed because otherwise subprocess.run wouldn't work properly.

Comment: I tried several times with minor variations but `subprocess.run` always causes error saying no such file or directory. Simply replacing `subprocess.run` in the given solution with `os.system` however works. Do not know if this is expected or weird but anyways work. I am using Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: You have to add `shell=True` to the `subprocess` command to make it work.